# Vue: Is it possible to set another state inside a Vuex action?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a Vuex action called `activateProgram` that I dispatch.  I would like a state set inside of there called `loadingData` to be set to true and then set it to false when the api request is finished.  I'd like to use this state as a flag for a spinner on my view.  Is this possible?

```
actions: {
    activateProgram: (context, data) => {
        /// SET A ANOTHER STATE RIGHT HERE TO MARK THAT A REQUEST STARTED
        return axios.post(data.url, data.request)
            .then((response) =>
                 /// SET THAT STATE TO FALSE WHEN THE API REQUEST IS FINISHED
                context.commit('toggleProgram', true)
            )
            .catch((error) =>
                context.commit('toggleProgram', false)
            );
    }
 }
```

Comment: Trying it out would've been faster than writing this question. Is there a specific problem you've run into?

Comment: Yes it is possible :-)

Comment: @Nit well, I'm asking more if this is in line with Vuex -- I mean, I know it's technically possible by just setting the state there but is that the preferred way or is it a hacky solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a fairly common pattern, borrowed from [this post](https://medium.com/@lachlanmiller_52885/a-pattern-to-handle-ajax-requests-in-vuex-2d69bc2f8984):

```js
const actions = {
  fetchApiData (store) {  
    // sets `state.loading` to true. Show a spinner or something.
    store.commit('API_DATA_PENDING') 

    return axios.get('someExternalService')
      .then(response => {       
        // sets `state.loading` to false 
        // also sets `state.apiData to response`
        store.commit('API_DATA_SUCCESS', response.data) 
      })
      .catch(error => { 
        // set `state.loading` to false and do something with error   

        store.commit('API_DATA_FAILURE', error)
      })
    }
}
```

Add a `loading` flag to your state. It may make sense to group `loading` and `toggleProgram` mutations together. The "pending" mutation could toggle the `loading` to `true`, while the "success" and "failure" commits would set `loading` to `false` and mutate the program state as desired.

Doing this for every ajax post could get tiresome, so a next step could be to [add an abstraction](https://medium.com/@lachlanmiller_52885/a-pattern-to-handle-ajax-requests-in-vuex-2d69bc2f8984).

Comment: sweet, this explanation is exactly what I was looking for. thanks!